# SQL Server 2016 Remote Connection Error 18456

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2

I have recently installed SQL Server 2016 on Amazon EC2 instance so I can start developing various SSIS / SSRS applications.

I have enabled Remote connections, opened port 1433 in the security group and windows firewall, and created a user 'myuser123' who is enabled and  and allowed SQL Server and Windows Authentication within the server properties.

I am trying to login using this connection

```
ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com\MSSQLSERVER,1433

SQL Server Authentication

username: myuser123

password: #########
```

The error message I am getting looks to be a user authentication error.

```
Cannot connect to ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com\MSSQLSERVER,1433

Additional Information

Login failed for user 'myuser123'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error 18456)
```

However when I Remote Desktop to the EC2 Instance and try to log in locally using the same username / password I don't have any problem.

Do you have any idea why this may be?

Thanks

M

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use a named instance rather than the default instance.  Did you setup named pipes, open port 1434 and all that jazz?

Comment: Hi - I have enabled Named Pipes in the config tool, but not set any up? Port 1434 is enabled in EC2.